# How to get rows from table with specific header using Xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I need to get all rows in an HTML table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dunkin Donuts</td><td>2 York Ave</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since there are many tables in the page I want to get the rows from this specific table.

Here is my Xpath:

```
table[tr/th/text()="Location"]//tr
```

I also tried:

```
table[tr/th[2]/text()="Location"]//tr
```

No elements are returned. Ideas on how I might get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your context node has no `table` children. You can fix this by globally selecting all `table` elements with `//table`. You also did not take the `thead` and `tbody` elements into account. Doing so results in the following XPath expression:

```
//table[thead/tr/th/text()="Location"]/tbody/tr
```